# Opening a link in a new tab in HTML with script (button)

Tags: javascript, button, hyperlink

How do I open a link in a new tab with JavaScript?

This is my current code:

```
 <button id="homePage" class="float-left submit-button">Home</button>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById("homePage").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "https://www.google.com";
 };
 </script >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.open(url, '_blank');` after the `location.href`.